# Simulink Mask Editor: replace block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to change a block of a subsystem to be a `built-in/Inport` or a `built-in/Constant` in Matlab/Simulink 2016b.

```
disp(PortStat)
switch PortStat
   case 'off'
       if strcmp(get_param([gcb '/eng'],'BlockType'),'Inport')
          disp('replace inport to constant')
          replace([gcb '/eng'],'built-in/Inport','built-in/Constant')
          get_param([gcb '/eng'],'BlockType')
          replace_block([gcb '/eng'],'built-in/Inport','built-in/Constant')
          get_param([gcb '/eng'],'BlockType')
       end
   case 'on'
      if strcmp(get_param([gcb '/eng'],'BlockType'),'Inport')
         disp('inport already exist')
      end
      if strcmp(get_param([gcb '/eng'],'BlockType'),'Constant')
         disp('replace constant to inport')
         replace([gcb '/eng'],'built-in/Inport');
      end
end
```

switching the checkbox leads to the following output:

```
on
inport already exist
off
replace inport to constant

ans =
myModel/Subsys/eng

ans =
Inport

ans =
Inport
```

The *BlockType* does not change. But why?

Further information:

- The Syubsystem is not a library object.
- I run `set_param(gcb, 'MaskSelfModifiable', 'on');` and the greyed out field *Allow library block to modify its contents* on the *Initialization* pane of the *Mask editor* is checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to replace_block is not correct. replace_block takes a block type and the system in which the replacement occurs. For your case the call should like,

```
replace_block(gcb, 'Inport', 'Constant');
```

or

```
replace_block(gcb, 'Constant', 'Inport');
```

for the reverse case. BlockType is 'Constant' or 'Inport' and does not include 'built-in' as you see in your display. Additionally the above call will replace all blocks inside gcb that have the source block type. So you cannot use this function if you have multiple blocks with same block type but want to replace only one of them.